# Updating ExtendedMultireferenceEditor when parent order is updated (Hybris SAP Commerce backoffice)

Tags: backoffice, sap-commerce-cloud

We are having an editor in backoffice which shows order details. This editor have `extendedmultireferenceeditor` to display list of order Entries. We have written an action which changes the price of order entries and then recalculates the order total. This is working fine but the order entry editor keeps showing the old values until we refresh the page.

We have used `cockpitEventQueue.publishEvent(event);` to publish an event which refreshes the order but not order entries.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by using below code.

```
DefaultWidgetModel widget = (DefaultWidgetModel)actionContext.getParameter("parentWidgetModel");
widget.setValue("currentObject", order);
widget.setValue("orderEntries",order.getEntries());
```

When using this code it is enabling the 'save' button on order. Not sure why.